# What does "spasmodic contractions of the diaphragm" refer to?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does anyone know what it means when someone says I have spasmodic contractions of the diaphragm?

Comment: spasmatic, with an s.

Comment: Such contractions are involved in coughing and sneezing, and possibly also hiccoughs (or hiccups).

Comment: It means hickups

Answer (score 1):

It's a convoluted way of saying they have a [hiccup](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hiccup)

> a spasmodic inhalation with closure of the glottis accompanied by a peculiar sound

Answer (score 0):

Spasmodic contractions of the diaphragm refer to ***[hiccups](http://www.observerbd.com/2015/07/22/100492.php):***

> - ***Hiccups occur when a spasm contracts the diaphragm, a large sheet of muscle that separates the chest cavity from the abdominal cavity***. This spasm causes an intake of breath that is suddenly stopped by the closure of the vocal cords (glottis).
> - ***This closure causes the characteristic "hiccup" sound.*** Hiccups affect males more often than females. Hiccups occur in practically every human being, including babies and older adults.

(www.observerbd.com)